# Acer aspire 3 dark camera

Tags: windows-10, acer-aspire, camera

I have acer aspire 3 a315-51 that has win10 x64.

I was speaking with my friend on zoom perfectly but then the cameras became dark!

It's not off, but I can only see my face only if I make it very close it (even though it's not clear).

I uninstalled the camera driver from the `device manager` and restarted the laptop but nothing was rewarding.

Suggestions?

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution? A friend of mine found his went dark during a Zoom meeting this week and I've not found a way to fix it, yet.

Comment: @SteveMorgan, not yet .. btw, you're right it was Zoom not Skype. It's the laptop of my younger brother. I just asked him and he told me Zoom not Skype.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed my webcam by going into the camera app and then into the settings and changing the "flicker reduction" from 50Hz to 60Hz. Hope this helps!

Comment: Worked for me in an istant! It should be accepted answer!